# Graphical Design Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-proposal, design

Could you make a Graphical Design Stack Exchange site?. I know there is an UI site, but -being a software developer who wants to learn more about the elemental theory and practice behind the discipline/process/art- I would very much like to see such a site.

Comment: Welcome to MSO, @duke! I've voted to close this question because MSO isn't the place for new site requests; we use Area 51 for that (as you have seen from John's answer). I know close votes can look harsh, but I have nothing against the idea or you personally, please don't take it that way.

Comment: I'm taking it very personal, you won't make it into my christmas list

Comment: Someday (very soon), we'll have a place to discuss the creation of proposals for Stack Exchange sites within [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). But site requests are still relegated to http://area51.stackexchange.com and off topic for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design

Comment: Exactly like that, just committed.

Comment: @duke - glad to help.  :-)  see you there!